# Run multiple binaries in same bazel container

Tags: docker, bazel, bazel-rules

Is there any way we can run multiple go lang binaries in a single container?

I want to run multiple binary images each present in its own docker image.
I tried using layers as shown below but the layers are not starting their corresponding binary in the image. And I am not sure how to start the binaries inside each layer either.

```
go_binary(
    name = "web",
    embed = [":go_default_library"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

go_library(
    name = "go_default_library",
    srcs = ["main.go"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:private"],
)

go_image(
    name = "foo",
    base = "@alpine_linux_amd64//image",
    embed = [":go_default_library"],
    goarch = "amd64",
    goos = "linux",
    pure = "on",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

container_layer(
    name = "service1-image",
    tars = [
        "//backend/services/service1:image",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

container_layer(
    name = "service2-image",
    tars = [
        "//backend/services/service2:image",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

container_image(
    name = "image",
    base = ":foo",
    layers = [
        ":service1-image",
        ":service2-image",
    ],
    symlinks = {
        "/foo": "/app/cmd/app/backend/foo.binary",
        "/service1-image": "/app/cmd/app/backend/services/service1/api.binary",
        "/service2-image": "/app/cmd/app/backend/services/service2/api.binary",
    },
)
```

I assume running `:image` target from the above build file will run all the go binaries in the layers but only the go_default_binary is triggered.
Is there any way I can run the other services in the same docker image?

Comment: The standard practice is to run only one process per container, though you could launch multiple containers from the same image.

Comment: Is there any way to run multiple process in the same container? I was able to do it easily with DockerFile on regular go binaries using custom scripts before I migrated to bazel.

Comment: If they're Go programs, you could `go` launch each component in a separate goroutine, and then they'd be in the same single process.  Since a container is a wrapper around a single process, that would get you the effect you want.